# What type of bird skull is this?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, bone

My aunt found this skull on the beach in Vancouver Canada. I believe it might be a type of bird, but I can’t place it.

It is about 5 inches (~13 cm) long and 2.5 inches (6.35 cm) wide.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like a fish to me.

Comment: definitely a fish frontal/parietal. It is too long and rugose to be a bird skull part. If you change the title you might get a some fish experts, who can identify species.