# Please help ID this possible fish skull

Tags: species-identification, zoology

Found on the shoreline of a tributary of the upper part of the Chesapeake bay in Maryland:

[image]

More pictures [here](https://photos.app.goo.gl/Cg8t4Ttsde4oDDDg7)

ichthyology??

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I suspect you're going to need better pictures from multiple angles to have a chance at an answer; from this view it isn't even clear you have a skull.

Comment: I don't disagree. I'm having trouble posting pics....it is definitely a skull. I will create a link to the other pics. Thanks for responding.! Please look if you have time. I have been collecting mammal skulls for quite some time & I am stumped.

Comment: Here is the link to more pictures.  Any opinions are greatly appreciated.  It's driving me nuts                                https://photos.app.goo.gl/Cg8t4Ttsde4oDDDg7

Comment: I think that's ichtyology because it's probably a fish, the comment says herpetology,

Comment: Similar to this https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/74087/what-type-of-bird-skull-is-this

Comment: Thanks for your input

Comment: I've fixed your image link — in the future you should be able to avoid this kind of problem by entering each link on a separate line.  ———— I recommend uploading some more of your pictures — questions with clear images from multiple angles are more likely to get useful feedback! ——— To me this looks like it might be part of a turtle skeleton rather than a fish skull, but that's really just a guess.

Comment: yes an ichtyology forum is not suitable for fish IDs cos ichtyos dont know that kinda thing as well as this forum does.